# Recursion reversing after reaching the solution

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to build a recursive solution to a problem but then instead my recursion is reversing as well and arriving at where it started.

In the code snippet attached to it, you can see that it starts with 20 and the answer is coming at 20.

But the list contains the actual values that the recursive steps produced while reversing the intended steps so the correct answer is the first item in the list.

I simply use the first item in the list as my answer but if my method returns the answer directly which is the intended intention of the method then it would be great. Thank you all for any responses or suggestions or solutions provided.

```java
public class DiscountRate3 {

// shorter version of the code with hardcoded values to test the result 
public double getDiscountRate(int purchaseSum, int leaseSum, double dr) {

        if( (leaseSum-purchaseSum) > 20) {
            purchaseSum = (int) getPurchaseSum(100000, 5000, 6, 40, 6, dr+0.1);
            leaseSum = (int) getLeaseSum(35000, 35000, 6, 40, dr+0.1);
            listing.add(getDiscountRate(purchaseSum, leaseSum, dr+0.1));
        }
        return dr;
    }

// this is the actual method 
private double setDiscountRate(int purchaseSum, int leaseSum, double dr, double spa, double svna, int pc, double tr, int el, double amtOfDeposit, double amtOfLeasePayments, double leaseTerm) {

        if( (leaseSum-purchaseSum) > 20) {
            purchaseSum = (int) getPurchaseSum(spa, svna, pc, tr, el, dr+0.1);
            leaseSum = (int) getLeaseSum(amtOfDeposit, amtOfLeasePayments, leaseTerm, tr, dr+0.1);
            listing.add(setDiscountRate(purchaseSum, leaseSum, dr+0.1, spa, svna, pc, tr, el, amtOfDeposit, amtOfLeasePayments, leaseTerm));

        }
        return dr;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DiscountRate3 discountRate3 = new DiscountRate3();

    //  When dr = 20;        73479.8311042524
    //  When dr = 29.8       78326.2156084622
    //System.out.println("PurchaseSum: " + discountRate3.getPurchaseSum(100000, 5000, 6, 40, 6, 30.5));
    double purchaseSum = discountRate3.getPurchaseSum(100000, 5000, 6, 40, 6, 20);

    //  When dr = 20;        91762.47427983538
    //  When dr = 29.8       79357.48181518461
    //System.out.println("LeaseSum: " + discountRate3.getLeaseSum(35000, 35000, 6, 40, 30.5));
    double leaseSum = discountRate3.getLeaseSum(35000, 35000, 6, 40, 20);

    System.out.println("" + discountRate3.getDiscountRate( (int)purchaseSum, (int)leaseSum, 20));

    System.out.println(discountRate3.listing.toString());
}

}
```

results in:

```
// THE RESULT ON THE CONSOLE 
// THE ANSWER IS THE FIRST ITEM IN THE LIST WHEN THE PURCHASE SUM AND THE LEASE SUM ARE ALMOST EQUAL 

20.0
[30.50000000000015, ... , 20.1]
```

Comment: You are getting same result as your last argument because you are just returning the value and not resetting it. 
Try setting the value of dr first and then add it to your list.

Comment: In your given code example there are many calls to methods not inside your example. Also fields etc. are missing. So please update / shrink the code by either adding missing parts or replace it by values to show a real example. IMHO it's difficult to help otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning the value returned from the recursive call.

You have (irrelevant code removed):

```
private double setDiscountRate(double dr) {
    listing.add(setDiscountRate(dr+0.1));
    return dr; // what was passed in to the method
}
```

I think you want:

```
private double setDiscountRate(double dr) {
    dr = setDiscountRate(dr+0.1);
    listing.add(dr);
    return dr; // what was returned from the recursive call
}
```

which would be a typical way to handle the returned value in a recursive call.